# How to create series-by-series representation of a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, time-series

How can I make a series by series JSON output of the dataset below?

Here is an example of my desired output, Can anyone advise me on the steps to take?

```
Something like this

{
    "series_id":"// some unique series id",
    "points":[
      [an array of date(time)/float arrays in ISO8601],
      ["2017-01-01", 12.7],
      ["2018-01-01", 13.1]
    ],
    "fields":{
      an object of any additional metadata available at the source that helps to describe and identify the data; a series representing Brazilian GDP might have two main keys: "country" and "concept" as in the example below
    }
}
```

[image: DataSET]

Comment: you can loop through your column names and build a dictionary, column-by-column; what have you tried so far?

Comment: So what is your expected output? Use actual data, not screenshots.  What have you tried and where do you need help? [mcve]